# Numpy - convert a double indexed array string representation to a double indexed array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having problems in converting back a string representation of a numpy double indexed array. 
The input is the following:

```
input = '[[  8.   5.   1.   6.]\r\n [  3. 173.   0.   9.]\r\n [  0.  49.   3.   4.]\r\n [  6. 165.   2.  41.]]'
```

I have tried `numpy.fromstring` and `numpy.frombuffer`, but none of them works, they throw the following errors:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__buffer__'
```

I have also tried a simple conversion:

```
input = numpy.array(input)
```

But when I run `numpy.sum(input)` I got:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should try not to get yourself into this kind of situation in the first place. You're going to have much worse problems than just what you're having now; the string representation of a large NumPy array will be *abridged* by default, discarding almost all of the data.

Comment: What you're asking for only makes sense as a recovery operation, not as part of your normal data pipeline.

Comment: Exactly, this is a recovery operation, otherwise, I would have never done something similar. @user2357112

Comment: Thank you for the link. Just as a curiosity, the only way to do that is by parsing the string? @user2357112

Comment: Well, *something's* going to have to parse the string, and I didn't find anything that comes with NumPy to parse the format the last time I checked. You can parse it manually, or insert commas and throw it into `ast.literal_eval`, or maybe insert commas and throw it into `json.loads` (which should be faster than `ast.literal_eval`).